# compile with cl.exe unicode casting errors

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

first the code compiles and runs with VS2010

but when I compile with cl.exe it gives

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'WCHAR [10]' to 'LPCTSTR'
```

the code is

```
char *fileName = "12.txt";
WCHAR ufileName[10];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, fileName, -1, ufileName, 10);

postFile(ufileName, clientSock);
postFile(LPCTSTR lpFileName, SOCKET clientSock)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that fails to compile?  The error message refers to parameter 1 but `ufileName` is parameter 5 in this sample.

Comment: You should provide the full command line you are using. Otherwise it is hard to tell what native type `LPCTSTR` maps to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to pass a `WCHAR` array to a function that expects a `LPCTSTR`.  [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2995/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-I-Win32-Chara) explains that `LPCTSTR` is an array of `TCHAR`s and that `TCHAR` varies in size for unicode and non-unicode builds.

Your code relies on `sizeof(TCHAR) == sizeof(WCHAR)` so you need unicode support to be enabled.

I'd guess that your build from within the IDE enables unicode while your command line build doesn't.  You can enable unicode support by adding `-DUNICODE -D_UNICODE` to your command line.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you compile then link your code using cl.exe please?

Comment: It requires *two* defines, -DUNICODE as well as -D_UNICODE.  The first one is for the SDK headers, the second one is for tchar.h